# Can't edit bit.ly destination url

Tags: url-shortening, bit.ly

I have Google drive pdf's shared link as the destination link for a bit.ly link. For some reasons I need to update the destination URL and I cannot find any destination link edit option on the platform.

How can one edit the destination url on bit.ly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### <sup>[image]</sup> bit.ly Paid Feature

This is a feature available only to paid accounts.

Excerpt from <sup>[image]</sup> bit.ly:

> With a paid subscription, you can edit the link destination by entering a different target URL. There is a [monthly limit](https://support.bitly.com/hc/en-us/articles/10796542543373) of how many redirects you can edit per month based on the type of link—a [custom link](https://support.bitly.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001626408) or a bit.ly link—and your [subscription plan](https://bitly.com/pages/pricing).
>
> A redirected link also counts as a new link, meaning it counts against your monthly link limit. If you hit your link limit, you won't be able to redirect any links until the start of the next month.
>
> To edit the destination of the link:
>
> 1. Log in to your Bitly account.
> 2. Click **Links** in the left sidebar.
>
> [image]
>
> 3. Select the link you would like to edit.
> 4. Click **Redirect**.
>    [image]
> 5. Enter the new target URL.
>    [image]
> 6. Click **Save**.

For more info see:
**[<sup>[image]</sup> How do I redirect a short link?](https://support.bitly.com/hc/en-us/articles/230900588-How-do-I-redirect-a-short-link-)**